# using a test runner for web performance tests

Tags: c#, unit-testing, load-testing, performance-testing

We are writing an app in MVC/C# on VS2013.

We use selenium web driver for ui tests and have written a framework around it to take make the process more declarative and less procedural. Here is an example

```
    [Test, Category("UITest")]
    public void CanCreateMeasureSucceedWithOnlyRequiredFields()
    {
        ManageMeasureDto dto = new ManageMeasureDto()
        {
            Name = GetRandomString(10),
            MeasureDataTypeId = MeasureDataTypeId.FreeText,
            DefaultTarget = GetRandomString(10),
            Description = GetRandomString(100)       
        };

        new ManageScreenUITest<MeasureConfigurationController, ManageMeasureDto>(c => c.ManageMeasure(dto), WebDrivers).Execute(ManageScreenExpectedResult.SavedSuccessfullyMessage);
    }
```

The Execute method takes the values in the DTO and calls selenium.sendKeys and a bunch of other methods to actually perform the test, submit the form, assert the response contains what we want.

We have happy with the results of this framework, but it occurs to me that something similar could also be used to create load testing scenarios.

IE, I could have another implementation of the UI test framework that used a HTTPWebRequest to issue the requests to the web server.

From there, I could essentially "gang up" my tests to create a scenario, eg:

```
public void MeasureTestScenario()
{
  CanListMeasures();
  CanSearchMeasures();
  measureId = CanCreateMeasure();
  CanEditMeasure(measureId);
}
```

The missing piece of the puzzle is how do I run these "scenarios" under load? IE, I'm after a test running that can execute 1..N of these tests of parallel, hopefully do things like Ramp up time, random waits in between each scenario, etc. Ideally the count of concurrent tests would be configurable at run time  too, ie, spawn 5 more test threads. Reporting isn't super important because I can log execution times as part of the web request.

Maybe there is another approach too, eg, using C# to control a more traditional load testing tool?

The real advantage to this method is handling more complicated screens, ie for a screen that contains collections of objects.  I can get a random parent record from the DB, use my existing automapper code to create the nested dto, have code to walk that dto changing random values then use my test framework to submit that dto's values as a web request. Much easier then hand coding JMeter scripts.
cheers,
dave

Comment: This doesn't sound like something that is appropriate for a unit test. There are a variety of tools to load test the site, but Unit Testing should be used to test the smallest possible unit to be sure it performs as expected.

Comment: I absolutely agree, this is not about unit testing.  We have a complete battery of unit tests which are small, focused, etc.  We also have integration tests, configuration creation tests, and even web/UI tests that we run as nUnit tests, some under nCrunch (for true unit and some integration tests) and some using the DXCore test runner (for UI tests). To us, NUnit is a handy way to execute code and assert results for all sorts of tests.

Comment: NUnit can work fine if your tests log enough data for you to extract performance information from there. If you have good logging it wouldn't be hard to write a log parser to give you performance information for all tests you run.

Comment: I don't think logging is going to be too hard - the hard part re: nUnit is finding a test running that can execute tests in parallel and allow dynamic scale up/down of the count of threads.

Answer (score 0):

While using NUnit as runner for different tasks/tests is OK, I don't think it's the right tool for performance testing.

It uses reflection, it has overhead, it uses eventually the predefined settings for webclient, etc. It's much better if a performance testing tool is used. You can use NUnit to configure/start it :)

Answer (score 0):

I disagree that NUnit isn't usable, with the appropriate logging any functional test runner can be used for performance testing. The overhead does not matter when the test code itself is providing data like when requests are sent and responses are received or when a page is requested and when it finishes loading. Parsing logs files and generating some basic metrics is a pretty trivial task IMO. If it becomes a huge project that changes things but more likely, I could get by with a command line app that takes an hour or two to write.

I think the real question is how much you can leverage by doing it with your normal test runner. If you already have a lot of logging in your test code and can easily invoke it then using NUnit become pretty appealing. If you don't have sufficient logging or a framework that would support some decent load scenarios then using some load testing tools/frameworks would probably be easier.